# Delete record from a list of record

Tags: list, ocaml, record, delete-record

I have a list of record where I want to delete a specific record :

```
list_clients = [{name = "c6"; number = 9}; {name = "c12"; number = 3}; {name = "c17"; number = 6};]
```

I'm quite sure that it is impossible to remove a record from the list, but I would like to know what is the best way to return a list without a specific record (let's say that I want to remove name = "c12" or any other name).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List.filter (fun {name; _} -> name <> "c12") list_clients
```

Comment: Thanks! Filter function was exactly what I wanted.